# After method finishes running it won't display in the viewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c

After this method runs I'm trying to display it on the view. For some reason every time I try to use the following at the end of this method it won't display:

```
[self viewWillAppear: YES];
```

I'm just trying to pass all this info into the viewDidLoad so that it will display.

```
 -(void)categoryDining{

    //Some method

[self viewWillAppear:YES];


};
```

EDIT:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   MapViewController *category1 = [[MapViewController alloc] init];
     NSArray *array=[self.navigationController viewControllers];
        switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0:
            [self.navigationController popToViewController:[array objectAtIndex:[array count]-2] animated:YES];
            break;
        case 1:
            [category1 startOp];
            [self.navigationController popToViewController:[array objectAtIndex:[array count]-2] animated:YES];
            break;
            // etc...
            default:
            break;
    }
```

and then the method runs in another viewcontroller:

```
-(void)startOp{
  //Method here
  [self viewWillAppear Animated:YES];
}
```

and as you can see I send the message to viewWillAppear. It doesn't load on the screen.

Comment: " display it on the view" - what does 'it' refer to?

Comment: Calling `viewWillAppear` will not make the view appear; you shouldn't call it yourself. If you want the view to appear, you need to push its viewController or add it as a subview of another view that is or will be visible.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand the question, but you shouldn't call `viewWillAppear:` yourself. It gets called by the view controller for you. Instead, you implement the method and do whatever you need to do inside it:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    // do stuff
}
```